# Partition Isuue while Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

When I am right now using the Windows operating system, and in that, and I have 512 GB SSD, and from that, I have right now 166 GB Un-Allocated space available. Now I want to dual boot to Linux Operating System. When I open Ubuntu 20.04 version and click on the Install Now button, after some parts they show me Partition windows but in that rather than showing the partition they show me a whole 512 GB space. They did not show me 166 Un-Allocated spaces and also did not show any Allocated space as well.

Comment: Have a look at the following guide. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-10-dual-boot Check step 4 in particular. You should be able to select “ Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10”. With this setting you don’t need to do the partitioning yourself

Comment: Don't skip the preparatory steps. You MUST disable Windows Fast Boot. You MUST fully shut down Windows (not secret-hibernate). A backup of your data is recommended, since mistakes on those steps may lead to data loss.